# Function graph - meet an even number of times each horizontal line

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

I got a really interesting as homework.

Find a formula (try to find as shorter formula as you can) for a function $f(x)$, such that its graph meet each line parallel to the $x$ axis (the $x$ axis also counts) an evn number of times!

It is also difficult to find such a graph! Please help!

---

Note:  I already posted this prblem with an other one, but for the other one I got an aswer, but not for this one, so I post it as a seperated question.

Comment: Are there any other restrictions? Does the domain have to be $\mathbb{R},$ or can there be gaps? Is the function required to be continuous?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a continuous function from the reals to the reals assume each value an even number of times?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1439689/can-a-continuous-function-from-the-reals-to-the-reals-assume-each-value-an-even)

Answer (score 1):

My proposal: $f(x)=x-x^{-1}$ on $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$

Answer (score 0):

How about $f(0)=1, f(1)=1$ on $\{0,1\} \to \Bbb R$  There is no continuous function from all of $\Bbb R$ onto all of $\Bbb R$ that takes each value twice.  That has been asked here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another one: $f(x)=2x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ on $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$

If the number of intersections with the parallel lines is given (e.g. $n$), you can use
$$
f(x) = nx-(n-1)\lfloor x \rfloor
$$

Answer (score 0):

Another option is $f(x) = \log(x^2)$ on $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$.