# Continuous function that reaches each value on its range exactly 2 times.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Is there a continuous function from $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ that reaches all of its possible values (each value in it's range) exactly $2$ times (for example, $x^2$ would be perfect if it wasn't for $0$..). Also, the same question but $3$ times.

I'm almost certain that there aren't such functions but who knows haha maybe there are a bunch...

Comment: See in particular : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/677085

Comment: I think the extra question about 3 times stops it being a duplicate of the second and third of those questions (and it's clearly not a duplicate of the first since the answer to that doesn't help here).

Comment: For “three times” it is answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/735842/function-f-mathbbr-to-mathbbr-that-takes-each-value-in-mathbbr-th.

Comment: @EspeciallyLime: Not sure why you think that [the answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1440533/42969) to the first one does not help. It says *"On the other hand, it is impossible for every point in the range of $f$ to have the same even number of preimages."*

Comment: @MartinR I meant the actual answer to the linked question, which is "yes", does not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there can be for $2$. To see this, suppose there is sucha function $f$ and consider two points $x_1,x_2$ where it takes some given value $y$. Between these points $f(x)$ is either always greater than $y$ or always less. Without loss of generality assume the former. Now there is some maximum value $z$ taken between these points, which is attained because $f$ is continuous. $z$ can only be taken at one point inside the range (since otherwise the function is constant on an interval, contradiction), but also every the function must be less than $y$ outside the interval since otherwise some value slightly more than $y$ would be taken three times. This means $z$ is only taken once, contradiction.

There is such a function for $3$. One example is the function defined by the following properties:

1. $f(0)=0$, $f(1)=1$, $f(2)=0$, $f(3)=1$, $f(4)=2$, $f(5)=1$, $f(6)=2$, $f(7)=3$, $f(8)=2$ and so on (after the first step it just repeats down, up, up)
2. $f$ is linear between integer values
3. $f$ is an odd function.